# the test -s for the "if" statement

Tags: bash

I have a question and i would be grateful for the answer if somebody knows one.
Ok, to the point. In one of my scripts i have following expression, it is not clear for me form man page what effect it should produce:

`if ! [[ -s "$the_file_to_check" ]] ; then echo "file is zero sized and not exist | is exist and zero sized | not zero sized and not exist | not zero sized or not exist | not exist (obviously zero sized)" ; fi`

there exist separate check for existence (the -a key), why to add another one?

And how this logics works in anyway.

I little bit lost in definition.

P.S.
I need a check for emptiness but not existence. Thank everyone.

Comment: that was the question about. it is unclear to me how the -s key exactly works if the check is negated.

Comment: Test with `-s` is true if: (file exists && file size is not nil). So `! -s` is true if (file doesn't exist || file size is nil). Could you clarify what your question really is?

Comment: If you are sure about it, then please form this comment into an answer. This was what i asked.

Answer (score 3):

`-s` checks not only if the file exists, but also if it contains any data (that is, if it has a size greater than 0 bytes). This is more than the `-a` option (which is, in fact, a synonym of `-e`) does, which only tests if the file exists.

```
touch foo
[[ -a foo ]] && echo "File foo exists"
[[ -s foo ]] || echo "File foo exists, but is size 0 bytes"
```

(I have wondered what the rationale for `-a` is, since I'm not aware that it does anything different from `-e`.)

Comment: -a is the first by alphabetical order

Comment: this man gniourf_gniourf gave most approximate description to what i asked. which was: what will happen when the -s key is used in negative context, because it actually includes two tests for one letter.

Comment: @chepner: from Posix: "An early proposal used the KornShell -a primary (with the same meaning), but this was changed to -e because there were concerns about the high probability of humans confusing the -a primary with the -a binary operator." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). Bash (and ksh) retain the old `-a` form for backards-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This if command simply prints the string `file is zero sized and not exist | is exist and zero sized | not exist (obviously zero sized)` if the file does not exist or if the file is zero sized.

If you want your `if` command to check only for the zero sized file and not file existence then you can do something like this :

`if  [[  $(du -h "$the_file_to_check" |cut -f 1) == "0" ]] ;then 
     echo "file is zero sized" ; 
fi`

But this `if` statement will post a error if file does not exist. Make sure you execute this only when the file is present.

Comment: the question was about the -s key in test, how it works. is there no chance to to check for the file's emptiness exclusively with only the bash means?

Comment: test -s checks if the "FILE exists and has a size greater than zero". So when you run `test -s filename` will return `0` if file exists and it's not empty. Returns  `1` if it's either empty or doesn't exist. You can check the return value  of  test command like this `test -s filename; echo $?`